# map over list columns and extract the first list item

Tags: r, dataframe, purrr

I have the following data which looks like:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  `Total_ Española_Porcentaje` `Total_ Extranjero_Porcentaje`
  <list>                       <list>                        
1 <dbl [3]>                    <dbl [3]>                     
2 <dbl [3]>                    <dbl [3]>                     
3 <dbl [3]>                    <dbl [3]>                     
4 <dbl [3]>                    <dbl [3]>                     
5 <dbl [3]>                    <dbl [3]>                     
6 <dbl [3]>                    <dbl [3]>
```

I am trying to map over the columns using `map` and extract the first `dbl`.

I have tried

```
df %>%
  map_dbl(., ~if(length(.x)) .x[1] else NA)
```

and

```
df %>%
  imap_dfc(., function(x, y) 
    tibble(!!y := map_dbl(x, ~if(length(.x)) .x[1] else NA)))
```

But I can't get it to work.

```
Data <- structure(list(`Total_ Española_Porcentaje` = list(c(5.9, 5.9, 
5.9), c(5.9, 5.9, 5.9), c(5.9, 5.9, 5.9), c(5.9, 5.9, 5.9), c(5.9, 
5.9, 5.9), c(5.9, 5.9, 5.9)), `Total_ Extranjero_Porcentaje` = list(
    c(5.9, 5.9, 5.9), c(5.9, 5.9, 5.9), c(5.9, 5.9, 5.9), c(5.9, 
    5.9, 5.9), c(5.9, 5.9, 5.9), c(5.9, 5.9, 5.9))), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `across` to loop over the `list` columns, then `map` over the elements of the `list`, `if` the `length` is greater than 0, select the `first` element or `else` returns NA

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
Data %>%
      mutate(across(everything(), 
       ~ map_dbl(., ~ if(length(.x) ) first(.x) else NA)))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  `Total_ Española_Porcentaje` `Total_ Extranjero_Porcentaje`
                         <dbl>                          <dbl>
1                          5.9                            5.9
2                          5.9                            5.9
3                          5.9                            5.9
4                          5.9                            5.9
5                          5.9                            5.9
6                          5.9                            5.9
```

---

Or as inspired from @ThomasIsCoding

```
map_dfr(Data, map_dbl, first)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  `Total_ Española_Porcentaje` `Total_ Extranjero_Porcentaje`
                         <dbl>                          <dbl>
1                          5.9                            5.9
2                          5.9                            5.9
3                          5.9                            5.9
4                          5.9                            5.9
5                          5.9                            5.9
6                          5.9                            5.9
```

Comment: Interesting (to me) that this sort of work can be done without any `map()` functions in `mutate()` if the work is done rowwise: `Data %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(across(everything(),  ~ if(length(.x) ) first(.x) else NA))`. On further investigation I learned working with list columns is a primary use case for `rowwise()`: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/04/dplyr-1-0-0-rowwise/

Answer (score 3):

Maybe we can use `pluck` from `purrr` package:

`pluck()` implement a generalised form of `[[` that allow you to index deeply and flexibly into data structures. https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/pluck.html

```
library(purrr)
pluck(Data, 1)
```

Output:

```
 pluck(2,2)
[1] 5.9 5.9 5.9
> pluck(Data,1)
[[1]]
[1] 5.9 5.9 5.9

[[2]]
[1] 5.9 5.9 5.9

[[3]]
[1] 5.9 5.9 5.9

[[4]]
[1] 5.9 5.9 5.9

[[5]]
[1] 5.9 5.9 5.9

[[6]]
[1] 5.9 5.9 5.9
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R trick

```
> Data[] <- lapply(Data, sapply, `[`, 1)
> Data
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  `Total_ Espa±ola_Porcentaje` `Total_ Extranjero_Porcentaje`
                         <dbl>                          <dbl>
1                          5.9                            5.9
2                          5.9                            5.9
3                          5.9                            5.9
4                          5.9                            5.9
5                          5.9                            5.9
6                          5.9                            5.9
```